# Redirect if match.params doesn't match ID in DB | React Router V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect to my home route if there's no matching `lockId` to a lock's id in my database. I'm getting `locks` from my Redux state.

This:

```
const lockId = this.props.match.params.lockId
const locks = this.props.locks || []
const lock = locks.find(lock => lock._id === lockId)
if(!lock) {
  this.props.history.push('/')
}
```

Works fine because I can see that my url is changing, but react still screams at me that it can't find `address`:

```
return (
  <div>
    <MainNavbar />
    <Grid>
      <Row className="show-grid">
        <Col md={12}>
          <h1 className="text-center">{lock.address.street}</h1>
```

And I understand why because of there is no lock that has that id, but that's why I want to redirect the user to the home screen. Should I use some other sort of React lifecycle method, like `componentWillReceiveProps`? I'm pretty stuck hehe

## Edit:

After Georgy's answer in the comments.
Do you mean something like this?

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.props.lock) {
    console.log("redirecting..")
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }
}
```

...

```
const lockId = this.props.match.params.itemId
const locks = this.props.locks || []
const lock = locks.find(lock => lock._id === lockId)
if(!lock) {
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this works:

```
if(!lock) {
  window.location.href = '/'
}
```

But it feels like this is not best practise for React development.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `componentDidMount`, it happen before render. And in the render method you should return null if lock doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, but seems you haven't `this.props.lock`, because you get `lock` as `locks.find(lock => lock._id === lockId)`